# High resolution rotary encoder

Tags: sensor, encoder, motion, rotary

I'm trying to find a way to translate small angle rotation into some form of digital signal. 1 degree resolution would be excellent, but something like 5 degrees would be ok.

I need something like a rotary encoder, but with much higher resolution, similar to what we see inside old rubber ball mouses, which have an encoding disk and IR leds/sensors to detect when the disk spins.

Is there any commercial component that would do that? Or I will need to build it myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: resolution of rotary encoders is expressed in pulses per rotation, you need something above 72 (5° per pulse) or 360 (1° per pulse). A quick google showed me several with 1024 p/r.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, thank you! I didn't know about the PPR parameter, this is the key to find these encoders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution of rotary encoders is expressed in pulses per rotation. One rotation being 360°.

In your case  you need something above 72 (5° per pulse) or 360 (1° per pulse).

A quick google showed me several with 1024 p/r.

Answer (score 1):

I know [SCANCON Encoders](https://www.scancon.dk/) have very high resolution optical encoders. Like 12500 real holes on a very small disk. It is like 34.72 real pulses per 1° (on a circle of 360°). So very high accuracy.